# How to run AsyncTask task within DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have

```
public static class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Would you like to share your contacts?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        readContacts task = new readContacts(); // The IDE doesn't like "new readContacts()"
                        task.execute();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

But the IDE says `'com.example.MainActivity.this' cannot be referenced from a static context`. But when I remove the `static` from `FireMissilesDialogFragment` declaration it says that `FireMissilesDialogFragment` should be `static`. So, isn't there any method to execute an `AsyncTask` within `DialogFragment`?

Edit: Here is my `readContacts`:

```
public class readContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){
    ...
}
```

`public class readContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {` is an inner class of `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`.

Comment: can you post code for readContacts class ?

Comment: `com.example.MainActivity.this' cannot be referenced from a static context` where you have used this context

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the AsyncTask a static class, then you can use

```
MainActivity.readContacts task = new MainActivity.readContacts();
task.execute();
```

However, I would suggest trying to make the AsyncTask a separate class so that you can reuse it elsewhere

And see [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)